# Regex to parse a duration string "xx'h' yy'mn' zz's'" in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a duration string that I like to convert to total seconds which could be one of these forms like "2h 32mn 58s" or "12h 2mn 8s" "46mn 15s" or just "45s".
The hours and minutes fields are optional, and all fields can be one or two digits. I'm new to Regex and I would appreciate a quick easy way to parse this in C#. Can Anyone help please?

Comment: or you could do as thousand of programmers without regexes did since ancient times... split it manually...

Comment: `I'm new to Regex` so what will you be next time you face a Regex problem?  An `experienced Regex question asker`?  Don't be lazy, give it a try.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083

Comment: [Quantifiers in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand you, but try this [.net regex tester](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=KD88VkFMVUU%2BXGR7MSwyfSkoPzxUWVBFPmh8bW58cyk%3D&t=MTJoIDJtbiA4cw%3D%3D)

```
(?<VALUE>\d{1,2})(?<TYPE>h|mn|s)
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked for me. And for those people that enjoy leaving negative and useless remarks: "Get A Life!"